# Django annotate not bringing back distinct

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I am trying to query a queryset in Django using annotate to get a calculation for each different 'field2'. The query looks like:

```
offer_lines.filter('field1'=x).order_by().values('field2').annotate(
                total=F('field3') * F('field4')
```

While I am expecting it to return something that looks like this:

[{'field2_value1': '1'}, {'field2_value2': '2'}]

I am getting multiple entries for the same field2 value. So it looks more like this:

[{'field2_value1': '1'}, {'field2_value1': '2'}, {'field2_value1': '5'},{'field2_value2': '2'}, {'field2_value2': '1'}]

I have order_by() in the query as I saw in other questions that it sometimes matters, but it did not help me. How can I query it to only return one entry per each unique field2 value?

Comment: provide your full model class and full query you are using. explain very clearly what output do you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try chaining the `distinct` method

docs - [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)